# Programmatic created folder with ACL not accessible

Tags: c#, .net, acl, windows-security

I had a lot of pain programmatic creating a folder with ACL and owner..

**Taks**:

Create a folder only accessible by one user (not even Administrator).

**(current) Solution**:

Run as Admin:

```
// path is the directory, "target" the parent directory
String path = Path.Combine(target, "Data"); 
DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(target);
// up is the "UserPrincipal"
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(up.Sid, FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl(target, ds);

// safeTokenHandle_SecureUser is the token of the already logged in User stored in "up"
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(safeTokenHandle_SecureUser.DangerousGetHandle()))
{
    ds = new DirectorySecurity();
    // Set owner only works impersonated
    ds.SetOwner(up.Sid); 
    // Inherited needs impersonation
    ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(up.Sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
    // Add Backupgroup
    ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-551"), FileSystemRights.Read, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
    DirectoryInfo directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(path, ds);
}
```

**Problem**:

Path created in "C:\temp\Sec53" (jea, count my tries.. but multiple tries are i the same directory..)

```
c:\temp\Sec53>whoami
pc-XXX\YYYuser93

c:\temp\Sec53>dir /q          (1)
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist Windows
 Volumeseriennummer: ...

 Verzeichnis von c:\temp\Sec53

13.02.2019  13:13    <DIR>          VORDEFINIERT\Administra.   (2)
13.02.2019  13:13    <DIR>          AAA\BBB                ..
13.02.2019  13:13    <DIR>          XXX\YYYUser93          Data
(TRIM)

c:\temp\Sec53>cacls *
c:\temp\Sec53\Data VORDEFINIERT\Sicherungs-Operatoren:(OI)(IO)(Beschränkter Zugriff:)    (3)
                                                              READ_CONTROL
                                                              SYNCHRONIZE
                                                              FILE_GENERIC_READ
                                                              FILE_READ_DATA
                                                              FILE_READ_EA
                                                              FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES

                   XXX\YYYUser93:(OI)(IO)F

(TRIM)

c:\temp\Sec53>cd Data
Zugriff verweigert  (4)
```

1. "Dir /q" shows the owner
2. User is: Predefined / Administrator
3. User is: Predefined / Backup operator group
4. Tranlated: Access denied

You can see, I'm logged in CMD with this user. The directory exists and the owner is the user. Permissions to this user are set to Full. But I'm still not able to change in this directory.

What is wrong? WTF? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, at try number 75..

two rules needed, one for current object, one for inherited..

```
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(up.Sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(up.Sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

In the question I only create the inherited rule (with wrong Flags).